# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot see built-in 3G modem Lenovo ThinkPad T410

Tags: 16.04, networking, modem, mobile-broadband, 3g

I'm a newbie and try to become friends with system. A have a prepaid 3G sim card, installed into built-in 3G modem of my Lenovo T410. I know it worked with another simcard 6 months ago, but now i cant launch the network connection manager (fn+F5). 
I created a new mobile broadband connection, but it's status is "no connected".
When i open the wi-fi connection list - there is no broadband connection in the list of connections. 
If you can, please help me to pass throw this problem, what should i do?